# Second call to dinktopdf pdf library fails

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, dinktopdf

I'm working on a invoicing app built on asp.core/Razor (.net core 6). I have a form in the app that is used to create the invoice. After a a user fills all the required fields, he can open a modal that will show a preview of the invoice. If he is statisfied with how it looks, he can confirm that he wants to save it to pdf.

On save, I have a jquery function that makes an ajax call to the OnPost function of the razor page.

The Onpost function passes the form data along to a C# function that creates pdf doc and signs it. On the first attempt it works, but on the second attempt the process just hangs. I get no errors or exceptions

EDIT: on the c# method, I convert the html to pdf and it seems the process gets stuck during the conversion of html string to pdf bytes

Comment: Check for any async with missing awaits.  This can cause things to "hang".  Otherwise it sounds like the pdf creation component is not exiting gracefully.

Comment: Could you share more details about your code?

Answer (score 3):

Edit:
I was able to solve the issue. The source of the problem was a html to pdf library i used named dinktopdf. The issue i encounterd was mentioned in github:

https://github.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/issues/62

I implamented the solution that was mentioned there and it worked:

remove `var converter = new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools());` and and replace it with dependency injection of 'IConverter' in your service: `private readonly IConverter _converter; public NameOfModel (IConverter converter){this._converter = converter;}`

Thank you all for your help.

**NEW EDIT**

First thing is to inject the service in Startup.cs Class

```
services.AddSingleton<IConverter>(new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
```

And then constructor injection in the NameController.cs or Any other class you are working with :

```
 private readonly IConverter _converter;
  
public   NameController(IConverter converter)
{
            this._converter = converter;
        }
```

**This should do the trick when your request is taking unexpectedly a long time or simply it just got hanged there**

Comment: Can you summarise the solution and include it here? Could be useful if someone else is using the same library and has the same problem, but 3rd party links to die over time.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a sealed class:**

```
 public sealed class  Dummy
 {

   public static readonly IConverter converter = new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools());

   private Dummy() { }

 }
```

**2. Call converter wherever you want:**

```
//inside of your controller class
//inside of your method

...
            byte[] pdfBytes = Dummy.converter.Convert(doc);
...
```